# How to measure allocation rate with jmh?

Tags: microbenchmark, jmh

JMH seems like it does most caliper features as well or better than [caliper](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U/7lY8x8SvHgwJ), but I couldn't figure out how to measure allocation rate, which is in general useful to be able to look at in a microbenchmark.  Is JMH the wrong tool to measure allocation rate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no accurate allocation rate measurement in JMH. This is a job for profiler, like Java Mission Control. In JMH, you can roughly estimate the allocation pressure by observing the GC counts via the MXBeans. This is wrapped by JMH profilers, e.g. `-prof gc`. Use `-lprof` to get the list of embedded profilers.

Comment: As of jmh 1.9 `-prof gc` prints allocation rates: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2015-April/001828.html